# wxTextCtrl Input Validation Issues

Tags: validation, wxwidgets

I am struggling to validate on wxTextCtrl, I want to have it so that certain characters (bcwyz) can't be entered, I tried:

```
wxTextValidator txtValidation( wxFILTER_EMPTY, &m_inputString );
txtValidation.SetCharExcludes("bcwyz");

m_inputTextBox = new wxTextCtrl( panel
                               , inputTextCtrlID
                               , "" 
                               , wxDefaultPosition
                               , wxSize( 170, 20 )
                               , 0L
                               , txtValidation
                               , m_inputString );
m_inputTextBox->SetMaxLength( 20 );
```

This isn't working and I really don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the sample is incorrect!

This:

```
// Now set a wxTextValidator with an explicit list of characters NOT allowed:
wxTextValidator textVal( wxFILTER_EMPTY|wxFILTER_EXCLUDE_LIST
                       , &g_data.m_string2 );
```

should be:

```
// Now set a wxTextValidator with an explicit list of characters NOT allowed:
wxTextValidator textVal( wxFILTER_EMPTY|wxFILTER_EXCLUDE_CHAR_LIST
                       , &g_data.m_string2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `wxFILTER_EXCLUDE_LIST` as a validator style if you use `SetCharExcludes()` (yes, I agree this is counter intuitive and poor API, the function should either turn on this style itself or at least complain loudly if it's not present).

Comment: Changed to wxTextValidator txtValidation( wxFILTER_INCLUDE_LIST, &m_inputString ); with no luck.  What am I missing please as I keep reading the help pages.

Comment: sorry wxFILTER_EXCLUDE_LIST, mistyped comment.

Comment: With `wxFILTER_EXCLUDE_LIST` it really ought to work, this is exactly what [the validate sample does](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/samples/validate/validate.cpp#L261) and it definitely works there (doesn't it for you?). The only strange thing I see in your code is passing `m_inputString` as name to ctor, this is probably wrong, but harmless.

Comment: I have compiled the sample code, wxFILTER_EXCLUDE_LIST doesn't work for me, the ALPHA filter does.  I am using wxWidgets 3.0.1